# ASP.NET Core custom validation client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I use ASP.NET Core 2.0 and have

```
public class Foobar
{
    [RegularExpression(EmbeddedCodePattern)]
    public string EmbeddedCode {get;set;}
}
```

This works pretty good with asp core and client side validation (jquery.validate.unobtrusive).

I want to create a custom attribute because I have to use this regex pattern multiple times:

```
public class EmbeddedCodeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmbeddedTrailerAttribute() : base(EmbeddedCodePattern)
    { }
}
```

In the end I have this:

```
public class Foobar
{
    [EmbeddedCodeAttribute()]
    public string EmbeddedCode {get;set;}
}
```

But client side validation doesn't work anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Attributes don't *do* anything by themselves. You need to [implement `IClientModelValidator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation) in order to make it function.

Comment: thank you @NightOwl888. But I don't understand why my approach doesn't work. I mean there is a working implementation of RegularExpression which works fine with client-side validation and I want to inherit from it to change the pattern. Why is the client side behaviour broken by just replacing the pattern?

Comment: Attributes are metadata compiled into the assembly. AspNet core uses `Reflection` to discover the attributes and then registers them in a special way in order to execute the logic within them. However, it won't discover types it doesn't know about and it won't execute them unless you extend the AspNet framework the right way. Technically, they implement 2 different extension points [like attribute filters do](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and there are *2 different instances* in the application. The only thing that connects them is they are implemented in the same class.

Comment: If you need custom validation on the client-side, maybe this framework can help you: [Dryv - DRY Validation for ASP.NET Core](https://dryv-lib.net). Disclaimer: I am the author.